# How can two Thrift servers communicate with each other?

Tags: java, client-server, distributed-computing, thrift, master-slave

I would like to set up some "slave" servers that should be managed by a "master" server, but I am unsure how the slave server could communicate with the master server (or vice versa) in Thrift - for example, the master knowing the status of each of the slaves.

I have tried researching this problem, but the only information I have managed to find is about client-server communication (which I have already succeeded in implementing).

Would anyone know how to do this, or be able to point me to documentation that describes inter-server communication in Thrift?

Comment: Tne current state of affirs is that you need to create a server and a client on both ends, or that you are using "long polling" which removes the need for the back direction but comes at a cost itself. There's plenty of material on the mailing lists, that is a very commion topic